# access a file with not fully known filename in python

Tags: python, char, filenames

I have a huge database of files whose names are like:

```
XYZ-ABC-K09235D1-20151220-5H1E2H4A.txt
XYZ-ABC-W8D2S5G5-20151225-HG2EK4GE.txt
XYZ-ABC-ME2C5K32-20160206-DD8BA4R6.txt
etc...
```

Names have all the same structure:

```
'XYZ-ABC-' + 8 random char + '%y%m%d' + 8 random char + '.txt'
```

Now, I need to open a file, given the date. The point is that, I don't know the exact name of the file, as there are some random chars within. For instance, for datetime 12/05/2014 I know the filename will be something like

```
XYZ-ABC-????????-20140512-????????.txt
```

but I don't know the exact name when using `f.open` command. What could be the best way to do this? (I thought about first creating a list with all filenames, but I don't know whether it's a good technique or if it's better to use something like `glob`...). Thank you in advance.

Comment: `glob` should do it, but what is `f.open`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code

`import os 
 fileName = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.startswith("prefix") and 'otherstring' in filename]`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks! This way it reconstruct the right filename. However, it produces a fileName string with [' and '], like `print fileName` gives `['XYZ-ABC-1W5G46EE-20150317-55CA1E2S.txt']` ... I preferred to split up the for and if cycle and it works well :)

Comment: Yeah i didn't actually try on my machine. i just wrote code at the same moment. Thanks :)